# Can not unlock sleep screen of windows 2016 virtualBox in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, screen

i am using windows 10 but i have to install windows 2016 in Oracle VM Virtual Machine to finish my midterm assginment, i have installed it successfully when it come to unlock sleep screen it tell me to hit `Ctrl + Alt + Del` to unlock

[image]
But my windows 10 OS it execute this command and function it concurrently and it take over all the screen side,

[image]
how can i deal with it? Thank you so much and have a good day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `Input > Keyboard > Insert Ctrl-Alt-Del`.

[image]